# Python saving csv data with extra line break

Tags: python, csv, scripting

I'm using httplib2 to pull csv data directly from an internal website. The data is already in csv format, so I'm trying to save it directly to a file using a simple file.write.

If I run the script in Linux, this works file. If I run the script in Windows (which is what I'll eventually be doing), it inserts an extra line between each row. Inspecting the file in Notepad++ shows a carriage return after each record, followed by a line feed/carriage return on the empty line.

edit: code

```
resp, content = httplib2.Http().request(request_string)
filename="data.csv"
abs_path=os.path.join(abs_path,filename)
file=open(abs_path,"w")
file.write(content)
file.close()
```

Comment: Are writing the data line by line ? then use line.strip() to remove the carriage return and then write to file

Comment: It looks like a line termination problem (\r\n on Windows vs \n on Linux). What line termination and csv dialect are you using?

Comment: Could you post the relevant section of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Just replaced \n with a space before closing the file.

```
file.read().replace('\n',' ')
```